400 on ajax post using microsoft studio debugging local. probally a __RequestVerificationToken issue
I seriously wonder why my post script doesn't work...
Watched many solutions here, but i can't get it seem to work.
Please help me out
I am getting a 400 status message in retrun..
What's wrong down here???
    var CandidateId1 = gettoken();
    var loCandidateId = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken"); //GetAntiXsrfRequestToken();
    var CandidateId = (loCandidateId[0].value);
    var PostAddress = "/Public/PostRemote";
    //alert(CandidateId1 + "\r\n" + CandidateId);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: PostAddress,
        data: JSON.stringify( {
            __RequestVerificationToken: CandidateId1,
            utititletlename: lsTitle,
            url: lsUrl
        } ),
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("S:" + response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, response) {

            alert("E:" + xhr  + "-" + response);
        }
    });


hope someone to help me ut, i don't think it's imposible to to avoid crosscripting on a local server
